# simple data subsetting on r

Tags: r, subset

I have a big df like following (pseudo) df and I want to retrieve values in different col. according to the rows in the first col.

```
A B C D
a 1 1 1
a 2 3 1 
a 3 3 3 
a 4 5 6 
b 5 6 5 
b 7 6 5 
c 7 6 5 
c 5 4 3 
c 5 5 4
```

I want to retrieve the values in col. B, C, and D according to the rows in col A and perform further analysis of them. For example, multiply the values in col B and C for all the rows of "a" in col A. Can someone suggest a commend for such a naive question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it doesn't have anything to do with bioinformatics, but you can use `df[df$A=='a',]`, or `dplyr::group_by(A)` if you want to repeat the same analysis for each value of A

Comment: That is not true, the original df contains genetic info. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because without more context, this looks like a programming question better suited for Stack Overflow, and the "this question belongs on another site in the SE network" radio button does not offer Stack Overflow as a selection.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that uses native R, using the vectorized (fast) family of `apply()` functions.

```
> df2 <- df[df$A == 'a', which(names(df) %in% c("B","C"))]
> apply(df2, 1, prod)
```

Use apply/lapply/mapply/etc. where you can in place of alternatives, where you don't know their run characteristics.

Here's a more concrete example:

```
> df
  A B C D
1 a 1 1 1
2 a 2 3 1
3 a 3 3 3
4 a 4 5 6
5 b 5 6 5
...
> df2 <- df[df$A == 'a', which(names(df) %in% c("B","C"))]
> df2
  B C
1 1 1
2 2 3
3 3 3
4 4 5
> apply(df2, 1, prod)
 1  2  3  4 
 1  6  9 20
```

**Edit**: If you need to do this on each unique value of `df$A`, you can nest `apply` calls to make this scale:

```
> perA.list <- apply(data.frame(unique(df$A)), 1, function(x) apply(df[df$A == x, which(names(df) %in% c("B","C"))], 1, prod))
> perA.list
[[1]]
 1  2  3  4 
 1  6  9 20

[[2]]
 5  6
30 35

[[3]]
 7  8  9
35 20 25
```

Each index in this list correspondents to the index of the value from `unique(df$A)`, i.e. `a`, `b`, and `c`.

If you don't want to do this for all unique values in `df$A`, but for some specific element in `df$A`, then you would just need to write a function. 95% of the code is in this answer to write such a function, so I'll leave that as a homework exercise for you to implement.

Comment: Thanks, I can't able to mention "a"every time. First I also want to have same results for "b" and "c" as for "a". Second, as I mentioned the data is big with 70,000 entries. In this case please suggest something.

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Hi, ddply (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/ddply) was used to obtain results, exactly what I was looking. Thanks